# C++ Smallest Number in Array Not Displaying

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{  
    double sixty = 0.0;
    double fiftyfive = 0.0;
    double height[10];
    double tallest = 0.0;
    double shortest = 0.0;
    double average = 0.0;
    double total = 0.0;

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    {
        height[x] = 0.0;
    }

    cout << "Please enter the heights of ten students. "<< endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter height of a student: ";
        cin >> height[x];
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    {
        if (height[x] > 60)
        {
           sixty = sixty + 1;
          }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    {
        if (height[x] < 55)
        {
           fiftyfive = fiftyfive + 1;
        }
    }
    cout << "The number of students over 60 inches in height: " << sixty << endl;
    cout << "The number of students under 55 inches in height: " << fiftyfive << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    {
        if (height[x] > tallest)
        {
                      tallest = height[x];
        }
    }
    cout << "The tallest student is: " << tallest << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    {
        if (height[x] < shortest)
        {
                      shortest = height[x];
        }
    }
    cout << "The shortest student is: " << shortest << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    {
        total = total + height[x];
    }
    average = total / 10;
    cout << "The average student height is: " << average << endl;   



    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

In the above, I need to spit out the # of students over 60in, the # of students over 55in, the average height, the tallest height, and the shortest height.

Everything works fine except for the shortest height. I return an output of zero for that portion of the code.

This is simple code so I imagine it's a simple problem which I'm overlooking. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you're using `x = x + 1` rather than, say, `++x`?

Comment: Any reason ***all*** of those limits are not computed in the *same* single pass of the array?

Comment: Using x=x+1 because that's what's used in all of our examples for this chapter (this is for an intro to c++ class). So I try to keep it on the ground the class is currently on.

Comment: How many students have a height less than `0.0`?

Comment: Most of this is "fancy C" more than it is C++. Using a C-style array is really a rough introduction to C++.

Comment: Side comment:  Your counters like `sixty` and `fiftyfive` should be an integer type rather than a floating point type.  Under strange circumstances you might end up with rounding errors that are hard to track down.

Comment: Many loops in this code can be merged into one loop by the way...

Comment: tadman I've never done C, but yes, this is a pretty brutal close to the semester.

Answer (score 4):

```
    if (height[x] < shortest)
    {
                  shortest = height[x];
    }
```

with shortest being zero there will never be a student smaller than that(unless you have students with negative height from outer realms ;) ). You need to init shortest with `height[0];`
Also in this case you can start iterating students from 1

```
shortest = height[0];
for (int x = 1; x < 10; x = x + 1)
{
    if (height[x] > tallest)
    {
                  tallest = height[x];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your loop to

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
{
    if (shortest == 0 || height[x] < shortest)
    {
                  shortest = height[x];
    }
}
```

or initialize `shortest` with first element from `height` array.

Your code will not work, since there is no height less that zero.

Comment: Am I too sober today, or won't `shortest==0` short circuit the eval to true on the initial pass ? **EDIT:** my bad. i was looking at *your code* not his. sorry (and +1)

Comment: Rather than testing `shortest == 0` I'd rather test `x == 0` which more clearly conveys the meaning and intent of "*on the first iteration*", but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

Initial value of `shortest` is zero

`double shortest = 0.0;`

and the loop can't find any height which is less than `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
{
    if (height[x] < shortest)
    {
         shortest = height[x];
    }
}
```

since `shortest` is initialized to `0.0`, if your `height` elements are all not smaller than `0.0`, then you will see `shortest` not changed. try the following:

```
shortest = height[0];
for (int x = 1; x < 10;  ++x)
{
    if (height[x] < shortest)
    {
         shortest = height[x];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have students with negative height, you probably have your comparison wrong.

Set your "shortest" height to a much larger value or the comparison will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

Initializa `tallest` and `shortest` to `height[0]` after you get `height` array as input...